# Spark Scala - TokenizerExample - Intellij Error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I am facing issue in compiling 'TokenizerExample' that comes along with Spark-Scala package.

I have setup my environment in IntelliJ and I am able to successfully compile other Spark-Scala examples such as NaiveBayes, CosineSimilarity etc.

But when I load the 'TokenizerExample' into IntelliJ IDE, system displays an error message on the below line stating 'Cannot resolve reference transform with such signature':

```
val tokenized = tokenizer.transform(sentenceDataFrame)

val regexTokenized = regexTokenizer.transform(sentenceDataFrame)
```

I have not done any edit and I could observe that the issue is with the transform method. Could you please help me address this issue? Appreciate your support.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SBT/Maven, make sure you have all the dependencies listed in the .sbt or pom.xml file for the mllib module and rebuild. I personally didn't work on mllib, but this kind of errors will show up if we don't resolve the dependencies well enough. Thanks.